# 4 chars to int in c++

Tags: c++, int, arrays

I have to read 10 bytes from a file and the last 4 bytes are an unsigned integer. But I got a 11 char byte long char array / pointer. How do I convert the last 4 bytes (without the zero terminating character at the end) to an unsigned integer?

```
//pesudo code
char *p = readBytesFromFile();
unsigned int myInt = 0;
for( int i = 6; i < 10; i++ )
    myInt += (int)p[i];
```

Is that correct? Doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Use `memcpy`. `*(int*)(p+6)` (1) can run into alignment problems and (2) violates strict aliasing. Endianness can also be an issue.

Comment: You need to essentially shift the bits of the different bytes into the appropriate positions. Depending on the endianess of the transferred value. The assignment in the loop may be `myInt = myInt << 8 | static_cast<unsigned char>(p[i])`. Alternatively you may want to loop through the loop in reverse.

Comment: Guys, those should all be made into answers, not comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code *might* work:

```
myInt = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(p + 6));
```

iff:

- There are no alignment problems (e.g. on a GPU memory space this is very likely to blow if some guarantees aren't provided).
- You can guarantee that the system endianness is the same used to store the data
- You can be sure that `sizeof(int) == 4`, this is **not** guaranteed everywhere

If not, as [Dietmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196313/4-chars-to-int-in-c/26196835#comment41077817_26196313) suggested, you should loop over your data (forward or reverse according to the endianness) and do something like

```
myInt = myInt << 8 | static_cast<unsigned char>(p[i])
```

this is alignment-safe (it should be on every system). Still pay attention to points 1 and 3.

Comment: Strict aliasing. You can't access the stored value of a bunch of chars through a glvalue of type unsigned int.

Comment: Another reason not to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous answer but just wanna add that this solution may not work 100% if the file was created with a different endianness.

I do not want to confuse you with extra information but keep in mind that endianness may cause you problem when you cast directly from a file.

Here's a tutorial on endianness : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4804/Basic-concepts-on-Endianness

Answer (score 1):

Try `myInt = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(p + 6));`.

This takes the address of the 6th character, reinterprets as a pointer to an unsigned int, and then returns the (unsigned int) value it points to.

Comment: This might be dangerous with regard to endianness

Comment: Because there is no `unsigned int` variable to look at.  We are looking at arbitrary memory, which requires a pointer.  `reinterpret_cast` only works on pointers for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using an union is an option? I think this might work;
UPDATE: Yes, it works.

```cpp
union intc32 {
    char c[4];

    int v;
};

int charsToInt(char a, char b, char c, char d) {
    intc32 r = { { a, b, c, d } };
    return r.v;
}
```